# Returning a reference of a local variable

Tags: c++, function, reference

```
int& f(){
    int x = 5;
    int& y = x;

    return y;
}
```

Why does the function above work? How is it possible to return a reference of a local variable which will be lost when of scope?

Comment: It's called Undefined Behavior, it can do everything, even work as expected. Till you try to use it in slightly different circumstances

Comment: It does not "work" since C++ does not specify what "work" means in this case.